# Geopandas GeoDataFrame.boundary raises null value error even if .is_empty returns False

Tags: geometry, geopandas, is-empty, boundary, isnan

I have a geopandas dataframe with an id column and a 'geometry' column. I am calling "boundary" onto the geometry column like so:

```
gdf_ops['start_end_points'] = gdf_ops['geometry'].boundary
```

But this raises a Value error:

```
ValueError: Null/empty geometry supports no operations
```

None of the rows seem to be empty geometries nor null rows

```
gdf_ops['geometry'].is_empty.sum() # returns 0
gdf_ops['geometry'].isna().sum() # returns 0
```

So my question would be what else could be leading to this value error, so that I know what to look after in the geometries to make the code work.

Cheers